# NestJS Fastify Bull Board integration

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, bullmq, bull

I'm trying to integrate Bull Board in to NestJS + Fastify service.

`bull-board.middleware.ts`

```js
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { router as bullBoardMiddleware } from 'bull-board';

@Injectable()
export class BullBoardMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    bullBoardMiddleware(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { BullBoardMiddleware } from './middlewares/bull-board.middleware';
[...]
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(BullBoardMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('admin/queues');
  }
}
```

Bull Board relies on Express application which has different Request interface.
Dashboard is actually reachable but serving static files fails.
[Browser+Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZBaM.png)

I tried:

- applying `fistify-express` adapter => causes errors with NestJS
- providing `basePath | proxyPath: 'admin/queues'` in `req` passed to `bullBoardMiddleware`

Can some one please advice how to make it working.

Thank you in advance!